# Which mobile development open source Framework should I use?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch-2, appcelerator, appframework

My company would like to develop a mobile application. Web app, native app or hybrid app ? They actually don't know. In that context, they asked me to make some researches (I'm not a mobile development expert) on open source Framework for mobile development (cross platform Framework btw). I did. 
Now, I have an overview of what actually exists and have selected 8 of them.

Now, what I would like is your personal feedback (pros/ cons/ like/ dislike/ if you left a Framework for another one, why ? ...) on those Framework/API below :

- Phonegap
- Appcelerator Titanium
- Senta Touch
- jQ Mobile
- Rho Mobile
- Xamarin
- DHTMLX

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry but this isn't really a question for SO : this site isn't tailored for "personal feedback" but for constructive definitive answers to precise and concrete problems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Related topics

I don't want to repeat my self so here are few of my older answers regarding this topic:

### Hybrid vs Native apps

[Struggling between native and phonegap, simple app requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065610/struggling-between-native-and-phonegap-simple-app-requirements/14069937#14069937)

### Use a web mobile framework?

[Use a web mobile framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166038/use-a-web-mobile-framework/14166593#14166593)

### Is jquery-mobile “mobile first”

[Is jquery-mobile "mobile first"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700648/is-jquery-mobile-mobile-first/15703204#15703204)

### Mobile App vs Web App - Apple no longer accepting web apps?

[Mobile App vs Web App - Apple no longer accepting web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436235/mobile-app-vs-web-app-apple-no-longer-accepting-web-apps/14436328#14436328)

### Top 7 mobile application HTML5 frameworks

**[Link](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-mobile-application-html5-frameworks/)**

### Top 7 notable less known mobile HTML5 frameworks

**[Link](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-notable-less-known-mobile-html5-frameworks/)**

## Books

Here you will find mobile frameworks enumerated by their popularity with few links related to relevant books and tutorials.

#### [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Books recommended by jQuery Mobile developers. They are on a intro level. For everything more come here to Stackoverflow. I found them ok but they are lacking certain advanced topics.

- **[jQuery Mobile First Look](http://www.packtpub.com/jquery-mobile-first-look/book)** - **2011**
- **[jQuery Mobile](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020585.do)** - **2011**
- **[jQuery Mobile: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014607.do)** - **2012**
- **[jQuery Mobile: Develop and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032182041X)** - **2013**

New book is coming soon from Pack Publishing. I will update this post once it becomes available.

#### [jQtouch](http://jqtjs.com/)

- **[jQuery Plugin Development Beginner's Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/jquery-plugin-development-beginners-guide/book?tag=sr/jqtouc/0610)** - **2010**

Good framework, unfortunately to little good material to start with. Faster then jQuery mobile, optimized for iOS latform.

#### [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

- **[Appcelerator Titanium: Patterns and Best Practices](http://www.packtpub.com/appcelerator-titanium-patterns-and-best-practices/book)** - **2013**
- **[Appcelerator Titanium Smartphone App Development Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/appcelerator-titanium-mobile-applications-development-for-smartphone-iphone-android-cookbook/book)** - **2011**

This framework is a wildcard. Technically not a HTML5 framework because it used javascript to create a real native app.

#### [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)

- **[Sencha Touch 2 Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026877.do)** - **2013**

New material. interesting framework if you have time to master it. Hard but fulfilling in the end. Would be much better if they would offer their builder tool for free.

- **[Sencha Touch in Action](http://www.manning.com/garcia2/)** - **2011**

## Tutorials:

#### Basics

- **[Struggling between native and phonegap, simple app requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069937/1848600)**
- **[jQuery performance on various mobile and desktop browsers](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement)**

Read this just to understand what are you getting into. A lot of developers comes here thinking that HTML5 hybrid mobile apps will solve all their problems. And because you already have an experience with Android development.

#### jQuery Mobile + Phonegap

**Windows**

- **[Building a Native Mobile App with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile 1.4](http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/)**

**MacOS**

- [**Creating Phonegap project on MacOS from Command Line**](http://www.gajotres.net/creating-phonegap-project-on-macos/)

#### Phonegap:

**Intro and installation:**

- **[First-phonegap-app-with-android-using](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html)**
- **[How to install phoneGap for Android using Windows and Eclipse](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.ch/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html)**

This is an easy how to tutorial how to create a Phonegap app from nothing to first real example.

**Usage with jQuery Mobile**

- **[jQuery Mobile, PhoneGap, and the Camera Device](http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/07/jquery-mobile-phonegap-and-camera.html)**
- **[Sample Application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/)**

While Phonegap and jQuery Mobile is not only existing solution it is probably the most common.

**Slightly more advanced**

- **[Phohegap docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs)**
- **[Building-a-phonegap-android-app-on-windows-cordova-2-2-0-with-eclipse](http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/building-a-phonegap-android-app-on-windows-cordova-2-2-0-with-eclipse/)**

You will find this link useful after some time of Phonegap usage.

An easy how to tutorial on how to use Phonegap with jQuery Mobile

#### jQuery Mobile

**Intro and basic stuff**

- **[Beginner’s Tutorial Coding Web Apps with jQuery Mobile](http://spyrestudios.com/beginners-tutorial-coding-web-apps-with-jquery-mobile/)**
- **[jQuery Mobile Tutorial: Basics](http://www.codeforest.net/jquery-mobile-tutorial-basics)**
- **[Beginner guide to a mobile app using the jQuery Mobile JavaScript Framework (with video)](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/5-minute-guide-to-a-mobile-app-with-jquery-mobile/)**

**Advanced**

- [**Use jQuery Mobile to Build a Native Android News Reader App**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/)

#### Other platforms

- **[PropertyCross](http://propertycross.com/)**

This is probably the best thing you can find. Basically this site has the same example created using numerous different HTML5 frameworks. You will find 27 examples, 8 frameworks + native app on 3 different platforms (Android, iOS and Windows Mobile).

> To help solve this problem PropertyCross presents a non-trivial
> application, for searching UK property listings, developed using a
> range of cross-platform technologies and frameworks. Our aim is to
> provide developers with a practical insight into the strengths and
> weaknesses of each framework.

#### [Phonegap](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://phonegap.com/&ei=N-9rUZ7DA8mE4ASIhIDIAg&usg=AFQjCNG1ra7Js9Qo6QGHtSOloIx4qGEnOA&sig2=pjQQ1fRrLccbgxNi6mLirg&bvm=bv.45175338,d.Yms)

Books recommended by Phonegap developers. They are good but quickly growing old. To be honest, I found much more useful examples here on SO.

- **[Mobile JavaScript Application Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025252.do)** - **2012**
- **[PhoneGap Mobile Application Development Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/phonegap-mobile-application-development-cookbook/book#overview)** - **2012**
- **[PhoneGap 2.x Mobile Application Development Hotshot](http://www.packtpub.com/phonegap-2-mobile-application-hotshot/book)** - **2013**

Comment: I see this compared a lot but assuming they connect to a database what do most people user for a backend?

Answer (score 0):

You have listed Phonegap first, that is the way forward, you have to know jQuery mobile to start using phonegap, thats all
http://people.phonegap.com/developer/okokoh-benjamin-ekuma/?sort=date_added&country=NG&region=&page=1

Answer (score 0):

See [Sigma Mobility](http://sigmamobility.com) http://sigmamobility.com  it has rich features for creating Mobile apps using HTML5,JS and CSS3; and also redirect mobile users to the mobile site created out of your app.

All of this can be done through free account.